# ltrying to list openembedded branches through git

Tags: openembedded

I am working on openembedded using bitbake. When trying to build an image using the bitbake command according to the openembedded and bitbake usermanuals (bitbake -b recipe name) or (bitbake recipe name) it produces this error:

ERROR: Please set the 'PERSISTENT_DIR' or 'CACHE' variable.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates an incorrect setup of the necessary environment variables for bitbake. Most likely, your BBPATH is either unset, not exported, or is incorrect. This error occurs when it is unable to load the basic configuration metadata from the conf/bitbake.conf file in the OpenEmbedded repository.

Answer (score 0):

Try this post: http://coax-users.203636.n3.nabble.com/ERROR-Please-set-the-PERSISTENT-DIR-or-CACHE-variable-td903113.html.

Someone solved the problem by just setting the source

```
$ source  ~/gumstix/gumstix-oe/extras/profile
```

Answer (score -1):

```
TMPDIR  = "${TOPDIR}/tmp"
CACHE   = "${TMPDIR}/cache"
STAMP   = "${TMPDIR}/stamps"
T       = "${TMPDIR}/work"
B       = "${TMPDIR}"
```

Just copy the above lines in bitbake.conf,it will definitely work.
make sure u remove all the spaces, and make sure these lines are the top five lines of the file.